# Shared Element Transition Android Doesn't Work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I'm trying to to this for a day but i don't know what is the problem! I have an activity with two fragments which in the first one i have a RecyclerView contains an imageview and on the other fragment i have another imageview.

custom view layer imageview:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/clst_img_cover"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_image"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_name_cover"/>
```

fragment two imageview:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_movie_cover"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_name_cover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@color/colorWhite" />
```

and in my adapter for the list view:

```
MovieDetailsFragment movieDetails = new 
MovieDetailsFragment().newInstance(String.valueOf(model.getId()));
FragmentManager manager = ((MainActivity)v.getContext()).getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    String a = v.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.transition_name_cover);
    cover.setTransitionName(a);
    movieDetails = new MovieDetailsFragment().newInstance(String.valueOf(model.getId()),((BitmapDrawable)cover.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
    Transition changeTransform = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition);
    changeTransform.setDuration(1500);
    MovieList current = (MovieList) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.activity_main_container_body);
    movieDetails.setSharedElementReturnTransition(new CustomTransition());
    movieDetails.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new CustomTransition());
    movieDetails.setEnterTransition(new Fade());
    current.setExitTransition(new Fade());
    String x = cover.getTransitionName();
    transaction.addSharedElement(cover,a);
}
else{
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fr_fade_in,R.animator.fr_slide_out_right,R.animator.fr_slide_in_right,R.animator.fr_fade_out);
}
transaction.replace(R.id.activity_main_container_body,movieDetails,"movieDetails");
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
transaction.commit();
```

and my second fragment has two newInstance method like this:

```
public static MovieDetailsFragment newInstance(String Movie_ID) {
    MovieDetailsFragment fragment = new MovieDetailsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, Movie_ID);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public static MovieDetailsFragment newInstance(String Movie_ID,Bitmap bmp) {
    MovieDetailsFragment fragment = new MovieDetailsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, Movie_ID);
    args.putParcelable(ARG_PARAM2, bmp);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

and this is CustomTransition.java :

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class CustomTransition extends TransitionSet {
    public  CustomTransition(){
        setOrdering(ORDERING_TOGETHER);
        addTransition(new ChangeBounds()).addTransition(new ChangeTransform()).addTransition(new ChangeImageTransform());
    }
}
```

it acts for the fade but doesn't work for the image!

**Update**
I suggest to use [this example](https://github.com/ebrahimkarimi/CircularImageViewTransition) in my git repository, its a great example for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i fined my ****ing mistake after a week.

**It's Best To Use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` thats why it wasn't work**

i mixed between `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `android.app.Fragment`

i highly recommend you to use [this](http://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-1/) tutorial, specially download the [git repository](https://github.com/mikescamell/shared-element-transitions)

Answer (score 2):

Please go through [this link](http://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-1/) and the link to his github is [here](https://github.com/mikescamell/shared-element-transitions). It has answers to all your queries. I had followed the same link.